# Flutter: Change the selected text color

Tags: flutter, dart

I change the selectionColor to white, but my text is white. How can I turn my selected text color to another like background text or the color on where the text is.

Without selection:

[image]

With selection:

[image]

I would like the color to be where the text is but I don't know if it's possible :/.

thanks!

Edit:
here a simple code-snippet for text selection theme

```dart
textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
    cursorColor: Colors.white,
    selectionColor: Colors.white,
),
```

I can't put more code-snippet because I want to text selected everywhere I can.

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as of now. You can follow this issue for more details.. Though if you wish to change color of selection you can do the following

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99231

```
ThemeData(
      textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
        selectionColor: Colors.blue,
      )
child: SelectableText()
),
```